# Can we remove a portion of code on a particular viewport?

Tags: html, css, viewport

Can we remove a whole div code below desktop screen size? If yes then how?

Comment: A basic google search can find out how to do this have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [Media Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), for example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
    div.class {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking for 
if you want to keep display screen data and remove other part which came after scroll you can use overflow property

```
body{overflow-y: hidden;}
```

but it is not a best practice.